# Overload PHP methods

Tags: php, overloading

I know that overloading in PHP is not available, and there is a workaround with the func_get_args. But my question is what could I do if I want to make a static and a non static version of the same method? For example I have a Profiles_Model class. Sometimes I may only want to get all profiles but nothing more, so I don't want to instantiate an object, calling a static method would be enough like:

> Profiles_Model::getProfiles();

But sometimes I may have an instantiated object from the class and I use other methods, and I would like if not only the class but the object itself had the same method like:

```
$pmodel=new Profiles_Model();
$pmodel->getProfiles();
```

Is there any solutions? This is what I would like:

```
class Profiles_Model extends Model{
    .
    .
    .
    public function getProfiles(){
        // do some stuff
    }

    public static function getProfiles(){
        // do some stuff with the same results
    }

}
```

Comment: If the result would be really same why you avoid calling static method with "self" or "static"?

Comment: I would avoid using methods with the same name that contain different behavior. Could be confusing and probably breaks single responsibility. I'm pretty sure that an instance of the Profiles_Model having a method called getProfiles() would return a list of the items it contained. calling Profiles_Model::getProfiles() suggests that the class knows something about how to get the profiles and therefore behaves differently.

Comment: If they produce the same result - why duplicate them? Plus I encourage you to use methods from objects (non-static), as they're twice as fast (as I can recall).

Comment: I somehow believe you can use func_get_args smartly with some anonymous functions depending on the quantity of arguments parsed

Comment: @kleskowy were talking about Microseconds of bare performance. If you had a query that took 30 seconds to run. Using static or method would be fractional difference in performance

Comment: @DarylGill that's right, but if it's executed very often it can  matter, especially when you have limited cpu. Just sayin'.

Comment: While there may or may not be a technical solution to this question, it sounds like a very bad idea architecturally speaking. A function should do a specified thing and be called in a specified manner. I can't see a use case for calling it "polymorphically", even less so if it does different things when called differently. IMO you're only setting yourself up for a world of hurt later on, without any discernible advantage.

Comment: @Kleskowy When using `static`s the performance is the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods can be called in the object manner, so having static method

```
Profiles_Model::getProfiles();
```

Will also be available

```
$pmodel=new Profiles_Model();
$pmodel->getProfiles();
```

but in the method you can't access object's properties, but only static fields and static methods.

But what you can trick is here:

```
class a
{   

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) 
    {
        if ($name === 'b')
        {
            echo  "a::b() called";

            return true;
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException();
    }


    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if ($name === 'b')
        {
            echo  "b() called in object context";

            return true;
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException();
    }

}
```

**example:**

```
$a = new a();
$a->b(); // b() called in object context

a::b(); // a::b() called
```